# Rails validation through parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have customer model having first_name,last_name and phone_number.
while creating a user I want to verify using phone_number that if 
phone_number exists then use same data otherwise create new customer.
How can I do that?

```
def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I tried this but It is not perfect

```
 def check_presence
     params[:phone_number].exists?
    end

    def validate_presence
     if !check_presence
       Customer.new
     end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

## customer model

```
before_save :check_phone

def check_phone
  Customer.exists?(phone: self.phone) ? false : true
end
```

Comment: not working. and i want to use same data of customer if phone number exists.

Comment: what do you mean by use same data of customer?

Comment: phone number exists means exist in DB or in field?

Comment: puneetgupta18190@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

In your customer model(customer.rb) you can do

```
validates :phone_number, presence: true
```

or

```
validates_presence_of :phone_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the method `first_or_create` method , a sample is posted below

```
@customer = Customer.where(:phone_number => phone_number).first_or_create(customer_params)
```

reference to doc : [Ruby Doc for First_or_Create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create)